# A linear operator T from an infinite dimensional complex vector space X to X which has no any eigenvalues.

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Give an example of a linear operator T from an infinite dimensional complex vector space X to X such that it has no any eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space $X$ must be infinite dimensional. Why?

Take the space $X$ having a countable basis $\{v_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and the operator $T\colon X\to X$ defined by
$$
T(v_{n})=v_{n+1}
$$
A nonzero vector in $X$ is of the form
$$
v=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
with $\alpha_n\ne0$; then
$$
T(v)=T(\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_nv_n)=
\alpha_1v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_{n+1}
$$
which cannot be a scalar multiple of $v$.

Comment: kindly give some hint to prove that it has no eigen values.

Comment: @Infinity Added some more hints

Answer (score 0):

Integration operator from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$ has no eigen values.